# How to validate multi select with jquery validate and Chosen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I am able to validate a multi-select with jquery-validate and have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/8rn89/3/) as demo.
Unselect the selection by holding Ctrl and click on the selection to see the effect.

```
<form id="myform">
    <select id="id_deals-1-sales_item" class="multi_select_mandatory" name="deals-1-sales_item" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Hotel 3 Star</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Hotel 4 Star</option>
    </select>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $('#myform').validate({
          // options
          rules: {
            "deals-1-sales_item": "required",            
        },

        //ignore: ':hidden:not("#id_deals-1-sales_item")'                                      
    });
});
```

But as soon as I chosenify the multi select it stops working: See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/vwHMT/1/).

```
$('#id_deals-1-sales_item').chosen();
```

While researching I found that someone has [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225928/validating-multiselect-with-jquery-validation-plugin) with `jquery multiselect` instead of chosen. It seems hidden elements are ignored in jquery validate. I tried to apply that solution but since Chosen has different methods, I got stuck (multiselect doesn't exist in chosen)

Is here any jQuery guru that could point me to the right direction? Besides I would rather have the solution based on classes rather than based on field names. Like this:

This is a solution I came up with half way through. But don't know how to proceed with `???`.

```
$.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function(value, element) {
        return $(element).???.length > 0;
    });

var validator = $('#myform').validate({
});

$('#myform').find('select.multi_select_mandatory').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            $(this).valid();
        });
        $(this).rules('add', {
            needsSelection: ""
        });
    });
```

**Solution:**

With eicto's solution below, I was able to create a class based instead of field name based solution. This is specially useful when you have dynamic elements that you want to validate instantly without submitting anything to the server.

```
    var validator = $('#deal_modal_form').validate({
        // options
        ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn-done)'
     });

    $('#myform').find('select.multi_select_mandatory').each(function(){
    $(this).chosen().change(function(){
        $(this).valid();
    });
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: this post explains issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232310/how-can-i-use-jquery-validation-with-the-chosen-plugin

Comment: also look at this plugin that has validation in it's API:  http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: Thanks Charlie. Regarding first comment, the suggested solution is on submit. I need it instantly though. Let me see that plugin. Maybe that helps...

Comment: I checked debugger, the problem is that `change` fires before `select` actually updates... even worse... it does not update selected....

Comment: @charlietfl the plugin seems neat but where do you see a minimum selection validation there?

Comment: @eicto looking at the fiddle, do you think you can fork it and show me your idea? I am not sure if I follow you. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $('#myform').validate({
        // options
        rules: {
            "deals-1-sales_item": "required",
        },

        ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn-done)'
    });
    var checkerrors = function() {
        validator.form();
    };
    var chosen = $('#id_deals-1-sales_item').chosen().change(checkerrors);
});​
```

the idea is to check form manually on each change.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vwHMT/8/)

Comment: I'm wondering to myself about the differences between `.checkForm()` and [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).  I'm not finding any documentation for `checkForm`.

Comment: [valid](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L435), [checkForm](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L355) not sure if it good idea to use checkForm, but it really different method, `valid` not check form data itself, while `checkForm` does

Comment: I'm not saying one way is better than the other as I've been unfamiliar with `checkForm()`.  However, `valid()` returns a boolean true/false regarding whether the form passes validation.  How could it do that if it didn't check the form data itself?    It also triggers any applicable error messages, almost like a `submit` without submission.

Comment: @Sparky [.valid](http://jsfiddle.net/vwHMT/6/) not works in that case, because it not invoke check

Comment: [.form](http://jsfiddle.net/vwHMT/8/) also works, but it does even more than `.checkForm` so i not sure that it is correct to use it here

Comment: @Sparky `valid: function() {return this.size() === 0;}, size: function() {return this.errorList.length;},` what trigger you talking about ? it just return current state.

Comment: Quote eicto: _"what trigger you talking about?"_ ~ [Please see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLsKQ/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21614/discussion-between-eicto-and-sparky)

Comment: I simply wanted to know the differences between the two methods for my own edification.  If you don't know how to explain, that's ok, because I don't either.  However, I am very familiar with how `.valid()` works... and simply saying that it does _"not check form data"_ [does not seem accurate](http://jsfiddle.net/dLsKQ/).

Comment: @Sparky I explained in chat

Comment: @eicto you got it working indeed. Masterpiece. I was able to create a class based solution from your solution, which I am adding as edit to the question.  Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have written my solution with the help of both @eicto and @kave solutions as follow:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("multiSelectRequired", function (value, element) {
    return element.length > 0;
});
$("#aspnetForm").find('select.multi_select_mandatory').each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });

    $(this).rules('add', {
        'multiSelectRequired': true
    });
});
```

When initializing the plugin I add `ignoe:[] in order to not to ignor hidden input from validation.

I am using special plugin for my bootstrap project called bootstrap-multiselect to render checkboxes select - https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselcet